# HP Proliant DL580 G5 Server Initial Setup

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, server-setup

I am a beginner so please bear that in mind if you choose to answer the question.

I have a HP Proliant Dl580 G5 with the following specs :
4x Six-Core XEON 2.4GHz E7450
128GB RAM
4x 72GB SAS 15K

I was wondering how i can go about installing or hosting 
4 Ubuntu Server OS running concurrently on it? 
ie Virtualization ? or Via KVM ?
Also If i should look into Xen or some other medium to make such a system possible.

Thank you in advance for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to run 4 different systems on a single hardware, you'll need virtualisation. KVM *is* a virtualisation system, it means "Kernel Virtualisation Manager".
The choice of a virtualisation platform among KVM+libvirt, Xen, ProxMox, VirtualBox or commercial products such as VMWare is up to you and depends upon your goals.

- If you prefer using a graphical interface, and plan to use your VM
  mostly for development purposes, VirtualBox is fine.
- If you want to run servers and have access to more powerful features, KVM +
  virt-manager is pretty good and still easy to use.
- For large scale systems, ProxMox or VMWare are probably better.